# Particular Thread Count

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I want to know how many active threads are there for a particular Thread class.
Lets say I have a class T which extends thread.  In some other class (Ex: Demo) , I want to get the thread count for the T class Thread. I do know `Thread.activeCount()` method but it will get the count for a thread group. It does not server my need here.  Lets say I have T1 and T2 classes which extends thread and In the Demo class I want to get How many T2 active threads are there.
How should I achieve this? Any Ideas??

PS: I don't have source code for the Class T1 and T2.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge Java does not gives you the ability to do this. You can only count all running thread in a pool as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Thread.enumerate()`:

```
public int countThreadsOfClass(Class<? extends Thread> clazz) {
    Thread[] tarray = new Thread[Thread.activeCount()];
    Thread.enumerate(tarray);
    int count = 0;
    for(Thread t : tarray) {
        if(clazz.isInstance(t))
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Plz read my updated post. I don't have access to source code for the class

Comment: @Stunner, Why you need the access to the source code to use my solution?

Comment: Thanks for the Solution @Tagir Valeev. It works.  But I see this  line in the API "Due to the inherent race condition in this method, it is recommended that the method only be used for debugging and monitoring purposes." Can you have a look at this api link once http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#enumerate(java.lang.Thread[])   I am concerned about this statement because If I am going to use this in production system.

Comment: @Stunner, of course you may have a race condition if some threads are started or stopped during the execution of this code. You will not get some crash, but the result might be incorrect. To make it more robust you can check whether the returned value of `Thread.enumerate` equals to the `tarray.length` and repeat in the loop first two lines if it differs. This is actually a dirty solution, so if you have a better way, consider the better way. You can use it if you don't control how these threads are created (probably they are created internally in some badly written library).

Answer (score 0):

Your `Thread` (or `Runnable`) subclass can maintain a `static` active count. Increment when `run()` starts, decrement when `run()` ends (in a `finally` block).

Make sure the increment/decrement is done in a multithread secure way.

Comment: The .subclass you are talking about is from Some API.. don't have source code. Infact even if I have source code to it. (infact I have) but I should not touch or modify the API (my requirement)

Comment: No I don't have control of starting the thread...The thread is started in the APi itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement [ThreadFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) to construct the custom Thread classes and supply a ThreadGroup instance to get the counts from. By using ThreadFactory, each instance could contain its own ThreadGroup, making counts accessible based on the factory used.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ThreadPoolExecutor`. 
You can extend the `ThreadPoolExecutor` and counts the number of threads by calling `getActiveCount()`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Answer (score 0):

```
   private static int getThreadCount(){
        int runningThread = 0;
        for (Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) if (t.getState()==Thread.State.RUNNABLE && t instanceof YourThreadClassName ) runningThread++;
        System.out.println("Active threads : "+runningThread);
        return runningThread;
    }
```

Justreplace **YourThreadClassName** with your class that is extended by Thread.